# Stop a background image from disappearing in IE when the inline element spans 2 lines

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[On this page](http://67.222.1.209/~acfund/) there is a list of footer links that have a little background image to place the dash before each one.  This works fine in FireFox but in IE 6, 7 & 8 the background image for the item that spans 2 lines (Workplace Giving Employers) disappears.  Why is this & does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean the Workplace Giving Employers link? The dash before that link displays fine.

Comment: I've added that in the question now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that before and although I don't know the reason it happens, you can fix it by changing your CSS to this:

```
#mainlevel-nav li {
   background: url(../images/arrow-vline.gif) no-repeat 0 3px;
}
```

The 3px is the vertical position of the image, so you'll need to adjust this until the graphic looks centered.

Since this is only needed for IE, I would recommend putting this in an IE only stylesheet since 'left center' is a better declaration.

**Edit:** Turns out this is a hasLayout bug.  Here's the CSS that'll do the trick for you:

```
#mainlevel-nav li {
   background: url(../images/arrow-vline.gif) no-repeat left center;
   zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't done it.  I've implemented that on the site, but the Workplace Giving Employers link still has no background image in IE

Comment: Whoops - my mistake.  See the edited CSS for the hasLayout fix.  That's what I get for answering without actually having the code working in front of me :]

Comment: It works.  This actually pushes the item onto the next line, but that's good enough I think, at least the background is showing